# 3 days fast breaking oath

Tags: sawm, oaths, kaffarah

I wonder when you fast for an oath you’ve made, for 3 days consecutive, do you break the fast each day on maghrib and then start the fast at fajr again? And then that counts as 3 days. Or do you abstain from food and water for 3 whole days?
Grateful for answer. Allah bless!

Comment: Abstaining from at least water for 3 days is equal to suicide. And Allah never orders something that harms his servants.

Comment: Thank you so so much for the answer, appreciate it. Allah bless you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you break the fast every sunset and stop eating at every dawn. You do **not** remain hungry\thirsty for 72 hours consecutively. An uninterrupted fast during day and night is called وصال and is generally makruh on the ummah.

> #### نهى رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم عن الوصال
>
> Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) forbade Al-Wisal
>
> <sup>— [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/30/68-71)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so so much for the answer, appreciate it. Allah bless you!